# Problem with useState in ReactJS and pagination

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios, react-hooks

I have a problem I can't fix with the `useState` of React.
I'm trying to make an API request of movies and a pagination but one of my states is `undefined` and I really don't understand why..
My component is a functional component.

Here is my `useState` :

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
    films: [],
    page: 1,
    genres: [],
    currentCategory: ""
  })
```

Here is my API request :

```
const getFilms = () => {
    Axios.get(`${baseUrlDiscover}&page=${state.page}&with_genres=${state.currentCategory}`)
      .then(response => {
        setState({
          films: response.data.results
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        setState({
          films: []
        });
      });
  }
```

The call of `getFilms()` to mount the component.

```
useEffect(() => {
    getFilms()
  }, [])
```

And I display the received movies with a `.map` like that :

```
const theMovies = state.films.map((film, idx) => {
    return <Film film={film} key={idx} />
  });
```

At this point I receive 20 movies on the first page but when I log the `page state` in my console for getting the second page I receive `undefined` . 
I would like to use this part of code below for getting the second page of 20 movies but without the `page state` I get an error like `state.films.map is undefined`

```
const btnClickNext = (e) => {
    if (state.films && state.page !== 500) {
      setState(
        prevState => ({ page: (prevState.page += 1) }),
        getFilms
      );
    }
    getFilms();
  }
```

And in the `return` I call `btnClickNext` function:

```
<Button
  href=""
  target="_blank"
  onClick={() => btnClickNext()}
>
  Next <FaChevronRight />
</Button>
```

Do you have any idea where the problem might be coming from ? and why `console.log(state.page)` gives `undefined` ?

Thank you very much

Comment: We dont have the code where you do your console.log(state.films), post it to help us

Comment: I made a mistake @JonathanDelean , it was "state.page" that was giving `undefined` but now I have the right value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this note](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) in the documentation:

> **Note**
>
> Unlike the `setState` method found in class components, `useState` does not automatically merge update objects. You can replicate this behavior by combining the function updater form with object spread syntax:
>
> ```js
> setState(prevState => {
>   // Object.assign would also work
>   return {...prevState, ...updatedValues};
> });
> ```
>
> Another option is `useReducer`, which is more suited for managing state objects that contain multiple sub-values.

With the current way you're doing state, using a single object for all your state, you have to spread out the other aspects of your state when just updating one item. So for instance instead of:

```
// Incorrect
setState({
    films: []
});
```

you'd do:

```
// Incorrect
setState(state => ({
    ...state,
    films: []
}));
```

**Don't** do this:

```
// DON'T DO THIS, IT'S LIKELY TO CAUSE TROUBLE
setState({
    ...state,
    films: []
});
```

State updates may be asynchronous and may be stacked up. If you do that, you may wipe out the effect of a previous update.

**But**, instead of using a single state object, I recommend reading [this entire page](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html). Fundamentally, with hooks, instead of:

```
// Not this
const [state, setState] = useState({
    films: [],
    page: 1,
    genres: [],
    currentCategory: ""
})
```

you typically want this:

```
// This instead
const [films, setFilms] = useState([]);
const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
const [genres, setGenres] = useState([]);
const [currentCategory, setCurrentCategory] = useState("");
```

Then use the appropriate `setXYZ` function. Instead `setState({films: []})`, you'd do:

```
setFilms([]);
```

---

In a comment you've said:

> I made a useState for each element and finally got the right one. My function increments the number of pages but I can't get the movies from these pages.

Because you've given it an empty dependencies array, your `useEffect` callback will only run once, when the component is first created. If you want the effect callback called again when something changes (for instance, if `page` changes), add that to the dependencies array. It looks like `getFilms` uses both `page` and `currentCategory`, so you'd include both of those. I'd also make them parameters in `getFilms` rather than having it use them from state:

```
useEffect(() => {
    getFilms(page, currentCategory); // ***
}, [page, currentCategory]);         // ***
```

Now the callback will get called when either `page` or `currentCategory` changes (but don't worry, it'll usually only get called once if you change both of them one right after another).

You might also consider cancelling an outstanding `GET` if you're starting a new one. (Or at a minimum, at least disregarding its result.)
See [the axios documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation) for details. From the documentation it looks like it uses the old now-withdrawn cancellable promises proposal.
Here's a version of `getFilms` that accepts a cancellation token:

```
const getFilms = (page, currentCategory, cancelToken) => {
    return Axios.get(
        `${baseUrlDiscover}&page=${page}&with_genres=${currentCategory}`,
        { cancelToken }
    );
};
```

Then you'd use it like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    let cancel;
    let cancelToken = new Axios.CancelToken(c => {
        cancel = () => {
            c();
            c.cancelled = true;
        };
    });
    getFilms(page, currentCategory, cancelToken)
        .then(films => setFilms(films))
        .catch(error => {
            if (!cancel.cancelled) {
                // ...handle/report error, then:
                setFilms([]);
            }
        });
    return cancel;
}, [page, currentCategory]);
```

Fairly clunky, maybe there's a better Axios-specific way (I don't use Axios). FWIW, here's a modern version of `getFilms` using [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) and [`AbortSignal`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortSignal):

```
const getFilms = (page, currentCategory, signal) => {
    return fetch(
```

`${baseUrlDiscover}&page=${page}&with_genres=${currentCategory}`,
            {signal}
        );
    };

Then you'd use it like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const controller = new AbortController();
    const signal = controller.signal;
    getFilms(page, currentCategory, signal)
        .then(films => setFilms(films))
        .catch(error => {
            if (!signal.aborted) {
                // ...handle/report error, then:
                setFilms([]);
            }
        });
    return () => controller.abort();
}, [page, currentCategory]);
```

I recommend [this article](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/) on `useEffect` (it's really about more than `useEffect`, it's about how functional components using hooks work).

Comment: Thank you very much, T.J. Crowder. I made a useState for each element and finally got the right one. My function increments the number of pages but I can't get the movies from these pages.

Comment: @Бастьен - I've added to the answer to show you some things to do with `useEffect`.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot @T.J.Crowder I didn't see that. I'm going to take a good hard look at all of this

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is not the way you should use useState
You should create seperate useState like this

```
 const [films, setFilms] = useState([]),
 const [page, setPage] = useState(1),
 const [genres,setGenres] = useState([]),
 const [currentCategory, setCurrentCategory] = useState("")
```

Wherever you need to update these states you can call the respective setter accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your help @rashijain , it works better and I can log the right page without errors in my console but now I can't update the component to display the movies on the second page..

Comment: You can call multiple setter at at time for example if I want to update the page and films I can do it like this
```setPage(2); setFilms([...films, {name: "Interstellar"}])```